# Android AsyncTask - Changing listeners

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` which never dies. The listener to the events in this `AsyncTask` keeps changing(depending on which activity/fragment is visible to the user). To accomplish this, I have a setup like the following :

- An interface :

> ```
> public interface TaskListener {
>    public void onItemChanged(String itemName)
> }
> ```

- AsyncTask which contains a `TaskListener` Member variable which is registered/unregistered using public methods.

> ```
> public void registerListener(TaskListener listener) {
>     mListener = listener;
> }
>
> public void unregisterListener() {
>     mListener = null;
> }
> ```

- In the `onPublishProgress()` method (called via `publishProgress()` in the `doInBackground()` method) of the `AsyncTask`, I notify the listener.

Now, my question is are there any caveats for this situation while notifying the listener? In particular, I would like to know whether it is thread safe or not. i.e., if `publishProgress()` and `registerListener()` is called at the same time, will the right listener receives a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had to debug an AsyncTask and followed my code even got into android's source code.

`publishProgress()` does not issue a direct call to `onProgressUpdate()` it just posts a message in a queue, and the queue handler eventually calls `onProgressUpdate()`.
So strictly speaking, if `publishProgress()` and `registerListener()` are called at the same time `registerListener()` will get there first.

If you are concerned about interference between the two, just enclose the sensitive code in a synchronized block over whatever variable is there.

```
synchronized(mListener) {
    // do stuff to mListener
}
```

do this in both `onProgressUpdate()` and `registerListener()` and anywhere else you want to be mutually exclusive on handling the listener.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` should not live between activities. That's not really correct way.
Android has `services` for this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

Comment: Why do you tell it should not live between activities?

Comment: AsyncTask is not intended for this, it intented to use inside one activity to do heavy work outside the UI thread. It has onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods that are related to activity-creator.
Services are exaclty intented to be used the way you use AsyncTask right now.